# Localstorage with React States

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm updating a user's cart with Localstorage and States,  but the updates don't happen until the user reloads the page. My code looks like:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    const data = localStorage.getItem('cart')
    setCart(JSON.parse(data))
 }, [])
```

I'm setting the user's cart when the page loads.

Now when a user increases the quantity of the item, for example, **ONE** cart item would look like this:

```
  const singleCartItem = {
    qty: 10,
    color: 'red'
    size: 's'
    productid: 'asdasd123213'
    }
```

Here is the function I use to update the quantity of the cartitem:

```
const incrementQty = (type, id, qty) => {

   incart.forEach(el=>{
      if(el.id === id) {
         const index = incart.indexOf(el)
         incart[index].qty = qty + 1
         localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
      }
   })     

 }
```

The issue, is here. I understand that localStorage won't update again until the page reloads, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Main issue is that you are mutating local state instead of updating it. It's because of this mutation that you don't/can't see the "updated" cart until you reload the page and the cart data you persisted is refetched.

```
const incrementQty = (type, id, qty) => {
  incart.forEach(el=>{
    if(el.id === id) {
       const index = incart.indexOf(el)
       incart[index].qty = qty + 1 // <-- state mutation
       localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
    }
  })  
}
```

A minor issue is that getting values from localStorage can return null if there's nothing previously stored. [storage getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem#return_value)

## Solution

You shouldn't mutate state directly. Shallow copy previous state into the next state, remembering to also shallow copy any nested state that is being updated.

You should also decouple the behavior of updating state from persisting it to localStorage, use an `useEffect` hook for this.

```
const incrementQty = (type, id, qty) => {
  setCart(cart => cart.map(
    item => item.id === id ? {
      ...item,
      qty: item.qty + 1
    } : item,
  ));
}

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
}, [cart]);
```

I suggest abstracting the local cart state initialization into a function.

```
const initializeState = () => ({
  cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || [],
});

const [cart, setCart] = useState(initializeState());
```

If you need to continue using a `useEffect` hook to load state, first get the cart state from localStorage, and if non-null update the `cart` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const cartState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  if (cartState) {
    setState(cartState);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: I wouldn't do const [cart, setCart] = useState(initializeState()) because I'm using localStorage with firebase, so if the user is not signed in, I use localStorage.

Comment: @TurtlesS I see. Does this mean the code in your question isn't an accurate representation of your *actual* code? You are free to continue using an `useEffect` hook to set state once mounted, the important issue there was the potential `null` value from the storage API. I updated my answer to reflect using the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: No, your solution works perfectly, regardless of me using firebase.

Comment: But is doing that important? Or perhaps I could do it, but it would just get overwritten if a user is signed in?

Comment: Also, I'm not too familiar with mutating states directly, so how would I be able to remove a cartitem from the cart array?

Comment: @TurtlesS Either way would work, but the difference is using the `useEffect` just means the initial render will have the empty array *and then* state is updated with the real data. This extra render usually isn't an issue at all. If you wanted to remove an element from an array the logic similar, use `.filter` to create a new array with the specific element removed, i.e. `setCart(cart => cart.filter(item => item.id !== id))`.

Comment: How would I only delete the items that match the color, size and id, instead of just id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233154/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-turtless).

Answer (score 1):

After you update the cart in localStorage just set the state again like you do in `useEffect`. In this case, you could create a new function and reuse it:

```js
const loadCart = () => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('cart') || []
    setCart(JSON.parse(data))
}
```

Then call `loadCart()` in `useEffect` as well as at the end of `incrementQty`.

**Edit**

I added `|| []` after the `localStorage.getItem` in case that returns null, so the default value in that case will be an empty array.

Comment: OP should also cover the case where getItem returns null